# How to safely sanatise input/output - strip html, etc

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the best method for stripping out html etc from submitted data using codeigniter?

(i don't mean to sanatise it for the database)

Are there built in methods of doing something like htmlpurifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

You should be able to do something like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('submittedData', 'SubmittedData', 
                                  'trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');
```

Comment: how well does does that sanatise the input?

Comment: trim gets rid of excess whitespace, xss_clean attempts to clear cross site scripting hacks, strip_tags gets rid of any kind of html tags